# Which camo has an effect on thermal signature?

Tags: battlefield-3

While playing with vehicles equipped with thermal vision, I've noted that some players are much less visible. I know that *Spec Ops* camo is supposed to give you that advantage, but are there any other camo types, which lessen thermal signature?

Does it work the same way with thermal vision as with IRNV?

(Extra question, how can I prevent falling back to default camo each time I start new game?)

Comment: To me it appears that when I edit my camo on my kit through the menu it doesn't carry in. I always have to edit my camo on the fly in game in order for it to apply correclty over all my games played. I think it is a glitch. This is on 360.

Comment: @Emerica: same on PC.

Comment: This is poppycock.

Comment: It's a known glitch that happens when you switch servers (or restart the game and join a new server)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've read, no other camo actually has any thermal benefits. It seems to only make a difference for those using the IRNV scope and thermal optics on vehicles.

You can change your camo in-game when you are in the spawn menu, open up your kit selection (not the quick select, but the one that shows your loadout) and press Y or triangle (platform dependant). This brings up the camo menu, just as it does in the main menu customization screen.